# media query for min-height

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I want to write media query based on screen resolution. My screen resolution height is 768. I wrote media query for this as:

```
@media(min-height:768px) and (max-height:850px) {
   .video-contain{
     margin-top:110px;  
    }
}
```

My above media query is not working.margin-top is not set before. I wrote media query based for screen resolution but not browser height.

Comment: Use `min-width` and `max-width` instead of height. Has that worked?

Comment: ya working but I have various height(900px and 1200px ) for  width 1600px

Comment: Then use multiple media queries.

Comment: you need to use javascript or jquery for check window.height based on that set your top margin...media queries use only for min/max width..its not works for height..

Answer (score 22):

Use:

```
@media screen and ( min-width: 850px ) and ( max-height: 768px )
{
   .video-contain{
     margin-top:110px;  
    }
}
```

***NOTE***: Always use max-width media queries to great effect.

Comment: "NOTE: Always use max-width media queries to great effect" 
Can you explain why ?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using max-width and max-height with multiple breakpoints, due to the fact that the size in media queries is specified in logical layout pixels and the device logical size can take floating point values. For example it can be 768.5px, which would be greater than the max-width and below the min-width at the same time, so no media query would be applied. Take a look at the example here: https://jsfiddle.net/lexkrstn/g2te9b89/

Comment: "Always use max-width media queries to great effect" I've always read that mobile up is the better approach.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the issue is that your viewport is not the full resolution of your screen.

If you set the min-height to something lower, such as 720px, it ought to work.

```
 @media(min-height:720px) and (max-height:850px)
{
   .video-contain{
     margin-top:110px;
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

`@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) and (max-height:667px) { }`

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 850px) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//simple max-width query
@media screen and ( min-height: 600px ){
    background: blue;
    ....
}
```

This might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can define as like this.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1600px) and (max-height: 900px){
    //code here
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1600px) and (max-height: 1200px){
        //code here
}
```

Or avoid mentioning width

```
@media screen and (max-height: 1200px){
            //code here
}
```