# Need minimum media queries

Tags: css, media-queries, media

IPHONE X is having screen resolution of 375*812. IPAD is having 768*1024. So how can write media query that will only apply to lets say IPHONE X landscape mode and should not apply to IPAD portrait mode. Same needs to achieve in android devices also like android phone and android tab.
Please help me with this with minimum media queries.

Comment: You can set a height requirement in your media query, but the less media queries you have, the better. Also, show us what you have - or that you have - tried

Comment: I would suggest you Google this as there are literally hundreds of websites related to media queries

Answer (score 0):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550541/media-min-width-max-width) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42407959/media-query-for-min-height) could help you.

You need to use the min-width, max-device-width, min-height and max-height properties of the media queries. Also pay special attention to the **orientation** property, wich let´s you define the media query as meant for portrait or landscape.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) you have listed all of the properties.